# Identifier followed by colon

Tags: javascript

I came across this piece of code and now I am baffled. I have never seen this `outer:` (line 1) and `break outer;` (line 8) before. Starting a statement with `name` + `;` and referring to it later

```
outer: if (oldDom == null || oldDom.parentNode !== parentDom) {
    parentDom.appendChild(newDom);
} else {
    sibDom = oldDom;
    j = 0;
    while ((sibDom = sibDom.nextSibling) && j++ < oldChildrenLength / 2) {
        if (sibDom === newDom) {
            break outer;
        }
    }
    parentDom.insertBefore(newDom, oldDom);
}
```

can anyone explain what this is called and what it is?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder why people think this is a duplicate. The other guy obviously knew what this is and wondered if it is legit to use.

Comment: Yeah, I for one voted to reopen this question (and either find a better dupe or leave it open).